# ubi-partman crashed with exit code 141 after formatting partition

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, ext4

I kept getting the error that ubi-partman crashed with exit code 141 while installing kubuntu from live usb. I eventually figured out that if I formatted my unallocated partition to ext4 in the live preview, then it might work. I tried and it still didn't work. I dont want to wipe my hard disk so is there any other way? Im dual booting the latest LTS version alongside windows by the way.
It occurred after the updates and other software tab and the exact error message was ```ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing?

Comment: Since you say you already have Ubuntu installed, are you trying to install to a USB stick?

Comment: Im trying to install from a live usb to my hard disk

Comment: Maybe helpful - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391201

Comment: A quick search shows a whole constellation of possible causes for Error 141: Corrupted .iso, bad burn. ACPI incompatibility with the hardware, Windows Dynamic Disks, etc.

Comment: 1. Ive already checked that site and nothing worked.

Comment: Have you looked in /var/log/syslog? It may be tedious, but at the moment we seem to have little to work with.

Comment: 2. Ive tried many different versions of kubuntu and they all returned the same error

Comment: I have looked but i dont understand anything in it

Comment: Put it in a [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) so we can see it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rP667Hgs sorry i didnt see the 2nd half of your comment because I was on mobile

Comment: Update: I tried installing it via VirtualBox and got the same error at the same place